# how DBSCAN can be used with track data/trajectory data

Tags: clustering, dbscan

I need to  apply DBSCAN clustering on trajectory data eg collected from RFID  readers from RFID tags at various points in the path defined.

HOw can I do  it using R ?

Comment: Can you expand your question somewhat?

Answer (score 1):

Compute a distance matrix using a suitable trajectory distance.

Define a threshold.

Run DBSCAN.

Comment: I have asked a similar question where your help would be much appreciated ! Thanks https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368100/trajectory-clustering-preprocessing-and-algorithms